# How can I use pandas groupby.count() for a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns, Ticker and Trade Results.

I want to create a new dataframe, with three columns - Ticker, Number of Trades, Profitable Trades.

I have used the `groupby` and `count` function to get the Number of Trades column, this works fine.

My problem is with the third column, Profitable Trades, where the Trade Result is > 0, I have not found a way to get in this condition.

**Creating DF (works fine)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Ticker': ['[BTC]','[ETH]','[LTC]','[BTC]','[ETH]',
              '[LTC]','[BTC]','[ETH]','[LTC]'],
     'Trade Results': [5,10,5,-5,-10,-5,5,10,5]}
)
```

| Ticker | Trade Results |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 5 |
| ETH | 10 |
| LTC | 5 |
| BTC | -5 |
| ETH | -10 |
| LTC | -5 |
| BTC | 5 |
| ETH | 10 |
| LTC | 5 |

**Grouping Tickers and Getting Count (works fine)**

```
df_Grouped = df.groupby(['Ticker']).count()
```

| Ticker | Count |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 3 |
| ETH | 3 |
| LTC | 3 |

**Conditional Column (my problem)**

This is the part I haven't been able to figure out, my latest attempt is below but returns NaN for the profitable column.

```
df_Grouped['Profitable'] = df.groupby(['Trade Result'] > 0).count()
```

**Desired Output**

| Ticker | Count | Profitable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTC | 3 | 2 |
| ETH | 3 | 2 |
| LTC | 3 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df_Grouped = df.groupby(['Ticker']).agg({'Trade Results': [('Count', 'count'), ('Profitable', lambda x: len(x[x>0]))]}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                 Count Profitable
0  BTC             3          2
1  ETH             3          2
2  LTC             3          2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always pre-filter, however I like @David M.s answer

```py
df_Grouped['Profitable'] = df[df['Trade Results'] > 0].groupby(['Ticker']).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a boolean for rows that are greater than 0, before aggregating on the groupby:

```
(
    df.assign(gt_0=df["Trade Results"].gt(0))
    .groupby("Ticker")
    .agg(Count=("gt_0", "size"), Profitable=("gt_0", "sum"))
)

    Count   Profitable
Ticker      
BTC     3   2
ETH     3   2
LTC     3   2
```